# Find the exclusive OR in an Array by the index, Java

Tags: java

I have a string of length 15: "10101000000010". i want to take the exclusive like below of every alternative index in the array like show below

'

```
    int s = a[3] ^ a[ 5] ^ a[ 7] ^ a[ 9] ^ a[11] ^ a[13] ^ a[15];'
```

//here ^ skips 1 index all the way up until the end of length of the string

'

```
   int t = a[3] ^ a[ 6] ^ a[ 7] ^ a[10] ^ a[11] ^ a[14] ^ a[15];'
```

//here ^ skips 2 index and lets 2 go, skips 2 lets 2 go... and so on

I dont know how to come about approaching this. Make a method with parameter the length of the array and have the method return an integer (0 or 1) which is primarily what its going to be since it's Exclusive or

So to clear it up again...  I want this to be done to any size array. like 17 now

```
    int z = a[3] ^ a[ 5] ^ a[ 7] ^ a[ 9] ^ a[11] ^ a[13] ^ a[15] ^ a[17]
```

THIS IS FOR HAMMING CODE

A byte of data: 10011010
Create the data word, leaving spaces for the parity bits: _ _ 1 _ 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0
Calculate the parity for each parity bit (a ? represents the bit position being set):

Position 1 checks bits 1,3,5,7,9,11: 
? _ 1 _ 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0. Even parity so set position 1 to a 0: 0 _ 1 _ 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0
Position 2 checks bits 2,3,6,7,10,11:

0 ? 1 _ 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0. Odd parity so set position 2 to a 1: 0 1 1 _ 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0
Position 4 checks bits 4,5,6,7,12:

0 1 1 ? 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0. Odd parity so set position 4 to a 1: 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0
Position 8 checks bits 8,9,10,11,12:

0 1 1 1 0 0 1 ? 1 0 1 0. Even parity so set position 8 to a 0: 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
Code word: 011100101010.

'

```
 int d[]=new int[7];
 for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
 {
 d[i]=sc.nextInt();
 }
 int p[]=new int[4];
 p[0]=d[0]^d[1]^d[3]^d[4]^d[6];
 p[1]=d[0]^d[2]^d[3]^d[5]^d[6];
 p[2]=d[1]^d[2]^d[3];
 p[3]=d[4]^d[5]^d[6];
```

'

Comment: I know it's not my business, but can I ask why?

Comment: Sorry I am confused what your second pattern says?

Comment: So you need code with a start index, and an array with the steps. Correct? Sidenote: your last example may have size of 17, but using index of 17 would make you out of bounds.

Comment: Why do you always skip index 0 to 2?  And your example string is only length 14?  Is it actually a string or an array?

Comment: @Braj The indexes form a 2-step pattern: skip 2 elements, skip none. So follows pattern of 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, ...

Comment: So This is your final pattern. Right?

Comment: Skip two elements means 0 and 1 index.

Comment: @Braj Since there's at least 2 different examples, I'm guessing OP wants a method that's generic, that you can send an arbitrary number of steps. But yeah, no code (or even logic) to show.

Comment: added something clear up any question it's for hamming

Comment: Added some code and added an example

Answer (score 0):

If perfomance allows, I would recommend using a for-loop.
initialize by 0, then, inside the for-loop check the index and perform XOR or continue.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna have a stab at some generic solution.

```
int source[] = ...; // fill the source array
int steps[] = ...; // fill the array of steps
int startIndex = 0; // assign value of first, 0 being the first element of the array
int result = xorMethod(startIndex, source, steps);

public int xorMethod (int startIndex, int sourceArray[], int stepsArray[]) {
    // going to ignore all tests, because I'm lazy
    int xorResult = sourceArray[startindex];
    for (int i=1, step=startIndex+stepsArray[0] ; step<sourceArrray.length ; i++, step+=stepsArray[i%stepsArray.length]+1) {
        tmpInt ^= sourceArray[step];
    }
    return xorResult;
}
```

It should be possible to also specify an upper boundary. The condition of the `for` loop would change to `for (... ; step<endIndex ; ...)` (or `<=` is you want endIndex to be inclusive) and `endIndex` would have to be passed as a method parametre, but otherwise if should work as a generic solution to your problem.

If you don't want a step, but want consecutive indices, you just have to have a value of `0` is the `steps` array, such as `int steps[] = {0};` or `int steps[] = {2, 0}`.

As an example:

```
int source[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int steps[] = {2};
int startIndex = 2;
int result = xorMethod(startIndex, source, steps);
```

And result should contain `source[2]^source[5]^source[8]`, or `2^5^8`.

Another example:

```
int source[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19};
int steps[] = {1, 2};
int startIndex = 0;
int result = xorMethod(startIndex, source, steps);
```

And result should contain `source[0]^source[2]^source[5]^source[7]^source[10]^source[12]^source[15]^source[17]`.

Comment: what does the steps array mean exactly?

Comment: Steps array contains the steps between the XOR-ed elements. If you want to skip one element, following pattern `1, 3, 5, ...`, it would contain 1 element, `{1}`. If you want to skip 1, then 2, and loop through that, `steps = {1, 2}`.

Comment: @user3550935 Let me know if this code helps, in which case, upvote and accept this answer as correct.